# Magento 2.4.2 - 2.4.5 - custom page builder element not working after upgrade

Tags: magento2, php, uicomponent, page-builder

We have a custom page-builder component for adding slides. The component has stopped functioning after upgrade to 2.4.5.

The admin panel page builder editor loads fine, we can add our component, it shows and can be dragged into a row / column with out issue. I can also delete the component as well as edit the settings for it, but the "+" / add slide does not respond no matter what.

I have reviewed console out put when it is clicked with no errors, I have reviewed error logs under var/log and we have no errors present when attempting to add custom slides.

I am not sure what may have changed for page builder between 2.4.2 and 2.4.5 but it has stopped our component from functioning. Please see image below:

[image]

Any suggestions on what may have changed between the M2 versions that may have broken this would be of great help.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I had similar problem, and this solution worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking your template files for these components - if you have self closing tags that aren't typically self closing (render, div etc) then this will break it in php 8.

Comment: Ah that was an excellent suggestion, it was unclosed render tags. Thank you, you saved quite a lot of investigation and debugging time.